# Compile C# project for different setup

Tags: c#, installation, project

I have a C# project where I have two variables that I change when I compile for another customer.

```
public static string DartklubNavn = "Min Test Dartklub";
public static Guid DartklubGuid = Guid.Parse("5c047b8f-6be6-4a94-8a9a-9cdeff758f45");
```

In my solution I also have a Microsoft Install Project that I use to make MSI files.

Then I change the variables to fit the current user, build my project and build the setup project.

Then change it again for the next customer and build again, and I do this for all my customers.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: You could put those two strings in a config (or JSON or XML) file and read them in.  Then you have one set of compiled code and a separate file that you package in for each customer.

Comment: I know I can put those values in different app.config files, but how do I do it smart when I have to build for each customer.

Comment: Ship the config (/json /whatever) file with your app, one per customer - all with the same name.  Don't build for each customer, just have your app start up and read that file.  If you want, name the file something like SomeCo.customer (for a customer named "SomeCo"), and have your code look for any file that matches *.customer